Updating donut with Chartjs
When I use the chartjs linear gaphic, my data is updated.
But when I use the donut chart, the data is not updated.
function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}

function addNewData(chart, label, data, new_label) {
    chart.data.labels[label] = new_label;
    chart.data.datasets[0].data[label] = data;
    chart.update();
}

My graph
const chart_11166a03 = new Chart($("#chart_11166a03"), {
        type: "doughnut",
        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Navigateur",
                data: [],
                pointStyle: false,
                pointRadius: 4,
                pointHoverRadius: 10,
                tension: 0.2,
                borderRadius: 1,
                backgroundColor: ["#845EC2", "#D65DB1", "#FF6F91", "#FF9671", "#FFC75F", "#F9F871", "#4E8397", "#00C9A7", "#DEB2FF", "#0089BA", "#008E9B", "#008F7A", "#4B4453", "#B0A8B9", "#C34A36", "#FF8066"],
                 borderWidth: 1
                fill: false
            }]
        }
    });
    var getData = function() {
        $.getJSON("data_chart.php?grr=liste_all", function (result) {
            $.each(result, function(i, field) {
                var count_length = result.length;
                if (chart_11166a03.data.labels.length < count_length) {
                    addData(chart_11166a03, field.navigateur, field.count_navigateur);
                } else {
                    addNewData(chart_11166a03, count_length-1, field.count_navigateur, field.navigateur);
                }
            });
        });
    }

update the graph when it is a donut.
my data is good in the console but I am unable to update unlike the online graph
